# Ensemble SVM in map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, classification, svm, libsvm

I am making SVM models for each dataset in Map Reduce(I am using LibSVM Library for that). Even , I have testing result of each model.
Testing result  file contain following details.(IT givens prediction about testing result)

```
+1
-1
+1
+1
..
..
+1
```

I have such 5 testing file. Now I want to combine testing result using Majority Voting in map reduce.
In map phase,I want to give line number as value of key . How can I give line number as value in map phase for all testing files.

Comment: Is that a requirement, or what you believe that will be part of the solution? Because I don't think that you need the line number.. You just need to sum all these numbers I guess and if positive +1 wins. Right?

Comment: SVMs are generally not a really well suited to using in bagging ensembles because they lack diversity. In geteral classifiers that have a a tendency to overfit tend to perform better when bagged. The following talk has a good discussion of issues in ensemble classifiers: http://www.sandia.gov/~wpk/avi/avatar-tools-background-video.avi

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need MapReduce for this task, but if you do need to do it in MapReduce, I would just use a Map-only job, and even that without an output file. Just using two counters (I didn't find a `decrCounter` method and `incrCounter` cannot take negative values). Here is a simple pseudocode for that:

```
enum MyCounter = {POSITIVES, NEGATIVES};
map(LongWritable key, Text value, Reporter reporter) {
    if (value.toString().equals("+1")) {
        reporter.incrCounter(MyCounter.POSITIVES, 1);
    } else {
        reporter.incrCounter(MyCounter.NEGATIVES, 1); 
    }
}
```

Then, if `POSITIVES > NEGATIVES`, +1 wins!

If you don't need MapReduce, you can just count the lines of all files, e.g. using `wc -l` command in Linux and then count the lines that have +1, e.g. using `grep -c`.